# LED power supply reverse connected?

Tags: power-supply

i have my 100 w - 220v AC to 12v DC LED power supply , and i connected the 220v AC line to the +VDC and the 220v AC Neutral to -VDC,

i know i seem to be a dump for you. but i hope if someone can help me fixing it.

Comment: Repair questions are off-topic here, and in any case you haven't provided nearly enough information, such as the make and model of the power supply.

Answer (score 4):

**You should definitely not be connecting an AC line to terminals labeled "VDC"**

those are the outputs, not the inputs.

Beyond that, there's not enough information to really answer your question.

Anything involving the AC mains is not territory in which you want to be experimenting without a very good idea of what is proper.